# Windows Phone 8 Memory performance

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, memory, windows-phone

This is graph of my memory usage.
I loaded Page1, then i navigated to Page2, then back to Page1. And again from Page1 to Page3 and etc.
Why app collects all pages in memory? And how to solve this?
I don't need in Page2, 3 and 4 when i returned to Page1.
I have a lot of data on each page, how to increase performance of memory usage?

[image: graph]

Comment: could you post some codes showing how your application navigated back to page1?

Comment: are you navigating back using back-key-press or by `NavigationService.NagigateTo`?

Comment: @lisp I use back-key-press